# Get Field Type as Interface

Tags: java, reflection, field

I'm trying to get a Map (Interface) from a Field. The Field looks like that:

```
private final Map<String, Object> test1 = new HashMap<>();
```

For that I'm trying to get the Value of it with

```
Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) field.get(field.getType().newInstance());
```

But the Problem is, that the type is an Interface and so I can't get a new Instance. How can I now get the value of the field when the type is an Interface?

And additional to that, how can I cast it always to the right Type?
So If the Map field looks like `private final HashMap<String, Object> test1 = new HashMap<>();` the Type is HashMap,
`private final AbstractMap<String, Object> messages;` type is AbstractMap, ...

Answer (score 0):

> Map map = (Map) field.get(field.getType().newInstance());

This would be incorrect even if the type wasn't an interface.  Instead, if the field is in a class named `MyClass`, you should pass some instance of `MyClass` to `field.get`, for the object you actually want to get the field from.  If you don't care which object, then the field should be static anyway, and you should pass `null` to `field.get`.

> And additional to that, how can I cast it always to the right Type?

You can't cast it always to the right type, and you shouldn't bother.  The
`Map` interface is all you actually care about.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't decide if the field is private, private static, public, etc. as I'm coding an API right now. With Class#newInstance() I am passing an instance, or not?

Comment: You are passing an instance, but almost certainly the wrong instance.

Comment: I don't really understand. I'm getting the type of it (returning a Class) and then creating a new Instance of it? But I'm getting too far from the theme. How can I get an Instance of Map?

Comment: I think you really need to figure out what this field is supposed to _mean_ before doing anything else.  But to get an instance of `Map` based on the field you just described, here is a complete solution with nothing left out: `new HashMap<>()`.

Comment: `Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) field.get(new HashMap<>());` -> Can not set final java.util.Map field mxrlin.randommob.file.Config.messages to java.util.HashMap

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  I meant for you to write `Map<?, ?> map = new HashMap<>();`, which is exactly equivalent to what it looked like you were trying to do.

Comment: No. You can't know that the field's value map is empty. I'm trying to get the Map of the Field.

Comment: It is always empty if the object is newly created, which is what `newInstance` does.  If you're trying to get the map from the field, you have to be getting the map from the field of _some specific object_ (of type `Config`, it sounds like).  Pass that object in.

Comment: `clazz.newInstance()` seems to be working. Next Problem is a private constructor, I'll try still getting an instance.

Comment: But if you get a new instance in this code, you'll always have an empty map anyway based on the code you've shown us.

Comment: @Mxrlin I think what Louis is trying to tell you is: if you create an object from scratch (`clazz.newInstance()`), then you know you will have an empty Map. So why doing reflection at all and not simply `new HashMap<>()` yourself? I think the whole point of doing what you're trying to do is to read a map filled with something from an instance you do not own, not an instance you create yourself.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)